# Adding users and groups

Tags: sudo

I am new to this and I am trying to create users and groups.  So far, I have the following:

```
sudo adduser Alice
sudo adduser Bob
sudo adduser Mike
sudo adduser Bill

#create groups
sudo groupadd student
sudo groupadd admin

#add users to groups
sudo adduser Alice student
sudo adduser Bob student
sudo adduser Mike student
sudo adduser Bill admin
```

I want to modify /etc/sudoers so that any admin can run /bin/kill as any user.

I am also looking to set passwords, which I am not familiar with.

Any assistance is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

In the terminal open up `sudo visudo`

Add the entry: `%admin ALL=(ALL) /bin/kill`

You set the passwords with the `passwd <user>` command.

Comment: Is there a ceratin location that I have to add  %admin ALL=(ALL) /bin/kill?